# Recommender System for continuous predictors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, inference, recommender-system

I want to build a model that is able to predict the outcome of a user-client interaction.
I know that for categorical variables Factorization Machines are a good choice.
Imagine for example we are talking about people interacting with movies: categorical variables for people are Age, Sex, ethnicity and so on, while for movies it could be release year, genre, main actor...

In my case both client and user are encoded with vectors of real numbers instead of categorical variable, like this:

- user1: [0.5, 1.2, 1.5]
- user2: [0.9, 1.3, 1.7]
  ...
- client1: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7]
- client2: [0.2, 0.5, 0.7]
  ...

I have data for most of the interactions:

| User | Client | Outcome variable (Y) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | client1 | 2.4 |
| user1 | client2 | 2.9 |
| user2 | client1 | 1.9 |
| user2 | client2 | 2.2 |

And I want to predict what could the outcome of the interaction be for pairs User-Client that have no measured Y.
This is exactly where a FM would work well but the difference is that i am using continuous variable as descriptors of both user and client and as far as i understand these algorithm are not meant to process this data.

Am I getting this right?
Do you know an algorithm that would work well in this case?

Comment: Pretty much any "regression" method (in ML parlance) would be possible, from multiple regression across tree-based methods (random forests, or gradient boosted trees) to different flavors of neural networks.

Comment: Yes but im really interested in getting the interactions between user client right. As you can read here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12859-016-0995-8 , RF and other tree-based methods may not actually uncover interactions as often reported

Comment: A dummy based regression model would work for small numbers of users and clients, e.g., the table above would expand to four dummy variables -- one for each user and client. Running the regression without an intercept would resolve the degrees of freedom, overfitting issue while interactions of the dummies would answer your question. How many users and clients are there? If a lot, then ANOVA inversion of a cross-products matrix would likely not converge. One work around is impact-based variables as described here. https://win-vector.com/tag/impact-coding/